# Newbie issue with DataContext and Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I'm definitely not new to C# and .NET, but since I haven't played with XAML for a quite a long time, I'm facing a pretty simple issue...

**I've created a test Model (`ResultsModel`) like this :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test_Project_
{
    public class ResultsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Monthly;
        public string Monthly
        {
            get { return _Monthly; }
            set { _Monthly = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Monthly"); }
        }

        private string _TotalAmount;
        public string TotalAmount
        {
            get { return _TotalAmount; }
            set { _TotalAmount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalAmount"); }
        }

        private string _TotalInterest;
        public string TotalInterest
        {
            get { return _TotalInterest; }
            set { _TotalInterest = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalInterest"); }
        }

        List<Dictionary<string, double>> _Items;
        public List<Dictionary<string, double>> Items
        {
            get { return _Items; }
            set { _Items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In my `MainPage` class :**

```
public ResultsModel Results;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Results = new ResultsModel();
    DataContext = Results;
}
```

---

**Now, here's the catch :**

When I'm trying to *bind* e.g. a `TextBlock`'s `Text` property to some of the simple string values of my Model (e.g. `Text={Binding Monthly}`), it works.

Now, please note that I also have a grid, with four columns.

I want to take all the items in my `Items` Property (`ResultsModel`) and show them in the grid by key.

**E.g.**

Show List item's "A" key, in column "A" (let's say the first column of the grid), etc.

How can I do that (in XAML and/or C# code)?

---

**UPDATE :**

---

(based on suggestions, I tried the following, but still not working)

Inside `Grid` XAML :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=num}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I'm getting the following error :

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'num'
>   property not found on
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   (HashCode=57616766). BindingExpression: Path='num'
>   DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'
>   (HashCode=57616766); target element is
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Text' (type 'System.String')..

Also, please not that `Items` has been converted to a List of string-string key-value pairs.

Any ideas?

Comment: instead of using a grid you should take some kind of itemscontrol to show your collection.

Comment: In WPF it's possible to use an indexer in a binding: `Text={Binding Path=Items[A]}`. I don't remember if it's possible on Windows Phone. In the worst case, you can use a converter to do the work for you.

Comment: indexer would work but then its not dynamic - and when its not dynamic you can create property getter in your model for each "hard" index

Comment: Add `Mode = TwoWay`on your bindings (both textBlock and column def).

Comment: @KooKiz Well, I admit I didn't know that. One more clarification : how is the "loop" written in XAML? I mean, if I just wanted a bound `TextBlock` in {0,0} I'd write something like `<TextBlock Grid.Column='0' Grid.Row='0' Text='{Binding Items[A]}'/>`. How would I go about if I wanted to so **ALL** `Items`' `A` fields in `Grid.Column='0'` `TextBlock`s?

Comment: @Jean Could you please clarify? Are `ColumnDefinition`s bindable?

Comment: Well, I assume, the value in column have the same keys as the value in your textBlock right? So, when your make your bindings on column and on textblock, can you try `{Binding Monthly, Mode = TwoWay}`. This works for me. Yes, you can Bind on your column. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Jean I think you're missing the point. First off, `Monthly` is just a string property. Now, as for `Items` (actually a `List` of Key-Value pairs), I want to have ONE row per item in the list, and each value going to the proper column - by key). Now, even if `{Binding Items}` works, **where** should I put it in the `ColumnDefinition`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- datatemplate to render your items -->
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <!-- wrappanel or what ever to control orientation and stuff -->
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Try `"{Binding Path=[num]}"` instead. But if you want to dynamically enumerate all the items of your dictionary, you may have to put another ItemsControl inside of your ItemsControl.

Comment: @blindmeis I was just writing my own Answer with the suggestion you just made. Yep, correct. Spot on. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try this in your binding :

```
{Binding Monthly, Mode = TwoWay}
```

In both of column definition and textBox.

When you writing your columns, you must have something like this :

```
<datagrid.column>
<datagridtextColumn header
binding />
</datagrid.column>
```

If I remeber well, you can make binding on column.

This must link value between textBlock and Column.

This can resolve your issue.

This works for me.